# Searching has_and_belongs_to_many relations for article categories

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

I have `Article` and `Category`, with a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relation between the two.

I want to use `Article.in_categories(category_ids)` to get any `Article` that is in any of the `category_ids` passed, and I want to handle the possibility of `category_ids` being `nil` in a way that all `Article` items are returned. The `category_ids` value is coming from a form, and I want the user to be able to ignore the `Category` selection part of the form if they do not want to limit their selection by that criteria.

I currently have this in place on the `Article` model:

```
def self.in_categories(category_ids = nil)
  category_ids.blank? ? all : includes(:categories).where(categories: { id: category_ids })
end
```

If I do not have the check for `category_ids` being `nil`, then it will only return the `Article` items that are not in any `Category`.

I do not want to manually set `category_ids = [1,2,3]` (for example) in the method call, because a `Category` can be added/removed.

Is there a better way of handling this than the way I already do?

Comment: Not quite an answer, so I'll comment instead: I'd suggest handling possible `nil` values elsewhere, and simply not call `in_categories` unless you have some IDs and it makes sense to do so. Right now, `in_categories` is basically a sometimes-alias for `all`, which smells weird to me. I'd expect it always filter the article records somehow, given its name.

Answer (score 3):

Generally you'll want to make sure this always gets passed an array so I'd choose to set the argument to an empty array rather than nil. Since in the successful case the method receives an array, you should treat it as such. If you ever expect to get a nil passed in (like you might from params), you can also catch if it is blank or empty to handle all cases safely.

If you get rid of the ternary, you can simply put a guard as the first line and that clarifies the method a lot more. You'll see the use of guards throughout the Rails source itself.

```
def self.in_categories(category_ids=[])
  return all if category_ids.blank? || category_ids.empty?
  includes(:categories).where(categories: { id: category_ids })
end
```

Alternatively you could always cast the parameter to an array and only handle that case.

```
def self.in_categories(category_ids=nil)
  category_ids = category_ids.to_a
  return all if category_ids.empty?
  includes(:categories).where(categories: { id: category_ids })
end
```

I've run into this "undocumented feature" on several occasions with Rails and it trips me up every time. Hopefully someone has a better solution so that Rails, but it is also good to just be explicit on the results if you can't consolidate.

Looks like there are quite a few discussions about this https://github.com/rails/arel/pull/245